# How to create line graphic with error bars and original points in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, linegraph, errorbar

I'm trying to create a line graph similar to what was done here:
[1]: https://community.rstudio.com/t/problems-with-a-simple-line-graph/75630. However, I'm not able to replicate it. I understand the code, but am not able to execute what I need.

Below is the code form the site mentioned above:

```
example %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(mean_val = mean(value),
            sd = sd(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=mean_val)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean_val - sd, ymax = mean_val + sd), width = .1) +
  geom_jitter(data = example, mapping = aes(x=year, y=value), color = "green", width = .1)
```

Below is is my line of code, trying to mimic the code above:

```
example %>%
  group_by(Time) %>%
  summarize(VAS.panel.ASD,
            mean_val = mean(Score),
            sd = sd(Score))
```

Below is a sample of my panel data:

```
example <- data.frame(ID = c(22308, 22308, 22308, 30958, 30958, 30958, 34708, 34708, 34708, 36158, 36158, 36158, 37308, 37308, 37308, 43508, 43508, 43508, ),
                      Score = c(4, 3, 7, 3, 2, 6, 0, 0, 5, 2, 1, 5, 4, 1, 8, 4, 2, 7),
                      Time = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: Could you clarify what's not working? Using the code from the site you mention in your post you could replace `year` by ´Time` and ´value` by `Score` to replicate the plot with your example data.

Answer (score 0):

My code is based on the example you provided (as well on @stefan suggestion), and I updated your sample data.

Sample code:

```
 gg<-example %>%
  group_by(Time) %>%
  summarize(mean_val = mean(Score),
            sd = sd(Score)) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=mean_val)) +
  geom_line(lwd=2) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean_val - sd, ymax = mean_val + sd), width = .1, lwd=2) +
  geom_jitter(data = example, mapping = aes(x=Time, y=Score), color = "green", width = .2, size=5)


gg+labs(x="Time",y="Mean value")+
      theme_minimal()+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, face="bold", size=12, color="black"), 
            axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
            axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
            axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
            strip.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
            plot.title = element_text(size=20, face="bold"))
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample data:

```
example<-structure(list(ID = c(22308, 22308, 22308, 30958, 30958, 30958, 
34708, 34708, 34708, 36158, 36158, 36158, 37308, 37308, 37308, 
43508, 43508, 43508), year = c(1992, 1992, 1993, 1993, 1993, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2005, 2002, 2001, 2005, 2004, 2001, 2008, 2004, 
2002, 2007), Score = c(4, 3, 7, 3, 2, 6, 0, 0, 5, 2, 1, 5, 4, 
1, 8, 4, 2, 7), Time = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), Value = c(4, 3, 7, 3, 2, 6, 0, 0, 5, 2, 1, 
5, 4, 1, 8, 4, 2, 7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I used the code, but I get this error:  In f(...) : no help found for ‘plot_data’

Comment: @Jarhed I removed the font family, so you won't receive any 'warning messages'. Otherwise the code is working fine.

Comment: Do you think you can explain a bit more why the dataset had to be updated? I initially provided a fictitious dataset that resembles the panel dataset because the dataset I have is quite long. Thanks!

Comment: @Jarhed as I remember the data that you provided was fine however in the example suggested there were more variables so I updated the sample data with those one, however I am not using them in the code.

Comment: I think the added variable was the standard deviation. Conceptually, do you know what standard deviation of what variable I need to calculate?